# Bug with scipy.linprog feasibility? (A_ub @ x0 <= b_ub).all() is True ---but--- linprog(np.zeros_like(x0), A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub) infeasible

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-programming

With numpy, scipy at versions

```
numpy 1.25.0
scipy 1.11.0
```

the following `scipy.optimize.linprog` call,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

A_ub = np.array(
      [[-0.15729144,  0.29943807,  0.29311432],
       [-1.32475528, -2.1125364 , -1.55138585],
       [ 1.00861965,  0.53283629, -0.14939833],
       [ 1.07581479,  0.164022  , -1.19889684]])

b_ub = -np.ones(4)

print(linprog(np.zeros(3),
        A_ub=A_ub,
        b_ub=b_ub))
```

return unfeasible status,

```
       message: The problem is infeasible. (HiGHS Status 8: model_status is Infeasible; primal_status is At lower/fixed bound)
       success: False
        status: 2
           fun: None
             x: None
           nit: 0
```

But the problem is actually feasible, since

```
x0 = np.array([ 229.1748166 , -507.05266751,  512.14005547])
print('x0 is feasible?', (A_ub @ x0 <= b_ub).all())
```

returns True. Shouldn't `linprog` returns a feasible point and a different status code and message in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html:

> Note that by default lb = 0 and ub = None.

So `x0 = np.array([ 229.1748166 , -507.05266751,  512.14005547])` is **not** feasible.

Comment: Thanks that was fast. Much appreciated. That the default ``bounds=None`` translates to ``bounds=(0., None)`` is questionably intuitive, although you are right that the docs are clear about it.

Comment: Actually, most LP solvers use this convention. For users familiar with linear programming, this default does not come as a surprise.